# Page stops rendering after PHP include() function

Tags: php, include, server-side-includes

Basically I'm having a go at using PHP to create a basic CMS for my website. I'm trying to write a script which creates a SPRY navigation bar from a CSV file, but the server stops rendering when it reaches the include() function which calls the script. I've checked the Apache error logs and there's nothing in there, also at the beginning of the script I echo'd a HTML comment, but that doesn't appear in the page source, so it would seem it doesn't even start to run? Any ideas as to what it could be?

Template Header File (Included with PHP in main page file, works fine):

```
<div id="header">
<div style="float:left; height:inherit;"><a href="/"> <img src="/uploads/logo.png height="150px" alt="Bradfield &amp; Bentley" /> </a> </div>
<div style="float: right;"></div>
<div id="navigation" style="clear:both;">
<p></p>
  <ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
    <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/templatefiles/navigation.php'); ?>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
<div id="contain">
<div id="spacer">
<p></p> 
</div>
```

The 'navigation.php' file (The one that the server stops rendering when included):

```
<?php
echo "<!-- File Opened -->";
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/templatefiles/navigation.csv', "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;
        echo "<li><a href=\"".$data[$2]."\">".$data[$1]."<a/><li><BR/>";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

?>
```

Comment: I found the issue, instead of '$data[$2]' it should have been '$data[2]' and also fixed all of the issues with my HTML tags in it!

Comment: which would indicate you don't have error checking\display on, which makes it very hard to develop anything

Answer (score 2):

try it with

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

the alternative to "having a error in your script" may be, that you have an endless loop and reach the memory_lmit and the thread is killed.

Answer (score 0):

Because this file has a syntax error

```
  echo "<li><a href=\"".$data[$2]."\">".$data[$1]."<a/><li><BR/>";
```

You cannot have numeric variable names. It should be `$data[2]` if you wish to access that index of `$data` array.

Comment: Why would it be down voted? can you shed some light on why this is wrong?

Comment: About 2 min ago the ts found the answer earlier. But still this is more clear for other people

Comment: "looks like" i have no idea if you knew or not. Of course you can always just delete your answer, once you find out.

Answer (score 0):

When a page stops rendering, this means a fatal php error. Include, however, doesn't throw a fatal error, just a warning. You probably have some error in that php file.

Comment: Right. I saw what You wrote.